# How can I disable mouse clicks inside an iframe in salesforce?

Tags: javascript, iframe, apex-code, apex

I have an iframe on a saleforce page and I need to disable mouse clicks inside the iframe. Is this possible?

here is my code

```
<apex:page id="peprtgdash">
<apex:form >
<iframe height="900px" id="pedash" name="pedash" src="http://www.site.com" width="100%" scrolling="false"></iframe>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

site.com is not the actual src it's just something i put in to not have my information be out there.

Comment: Maybe a transparent `div` over the top?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
   <apex:page id="peprtgdash">
   <apex:form >        
   <div id="wrapper" style="position: relative;">
        <div id="block" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 900px"></div>
         <iframe height="900px" id="pedash" name="pedash" src="http://www.site.com" width="100%" scrolling="false"></iframe>
    </div>
    </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

Comment: ok... how does it not work? Here is a jsfiddle proving it works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/d59e9/

Comment: well i'm still able to click on items and it takes me out to a log in page which is what i'm trying to prohibit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `div` over `iframe`. So, `div` goes after `iframe`:

```
...
    <iframe height="900px" id="pedash" name="pedash" src="http://example.com" width="100%" scrolling="false"></iframe>
    <div id="block" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 900px"></div>
...
```